# Page navigation in WPF Modern UI

Tags: c#, wpf, modern-ui

I started using Modern UI in WPF application. I can't find nowhere answer to my question: how set source for link to page that is localized in other project? I've got project ErpSystem with MainWindow in which i want to use page localized in project LogisticModule. When i'm setting source to this value: LogisticModule.View.WarehousePage.xml i've got error that navigation failed and it couldn't localized resource LogisticModule.View.WarehousePage.xml. What am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use a correct URI to reference the user control from other project. Probably something like this:

> "/ReferencedAssembly;component/ResourceFile.xaml"

In you case something similar to:

> "/LogisticsModule;component/View/WarehousePage.xaml"

You can find more about URIs in WPF [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa970069%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

Comment: thank you for your answer. I didn't even know how to look for the answer. Now it's clear and work perfectly.