# How to navigate links by button in WPF Modern UI in C#?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, modern-ui

I am using [ModernUI](http://mui.codeplex.com/). I have one issue with Button and link.

I am trying to navigate by Button Click event and my code in "Home.xaml" is as follow

```
private void addGameButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    BBCodeBlock bs = new BBCodeBlock();
    try
    {
        bs.LinkNavigator.Navigate(new Uri("pack://application:/Pages/AddGame.xaml"), null);
    }
    catch (Exception error)
    {
        ModernDialog.ShowMessage(error.Message, FirstFloor.ModernUI.Resources.NavigationFailed, MessageBoxButton.OK);
    }
}
```

mui:Link works fine in MainWindows.xaml for navigation. but I want to navigate to AddGame.xaml from Home.xaml Page by a Button, which is in Home.xaml page.

My file structure is as below, for reference.

[image: Folder Structure]

So please let me know, where am i doing wrong?

Comment: Look at the [documentation](http://mui.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Link%20navigation%20with%20BBCodeBlock&referringTitle=Documentation) to make sure that Uri is correct.

Comment: i tried many ways but not able to get the solution. even i tried stackoverflow link - [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20031163/page-navigation-in-wpf-modern-ui]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The second parameter of bs.LinkNavigator.Navigate method is **source** that cannot be null. Try this:

```
private void addGameButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    BBCodeBlock bs = new BBCodeBlock();
    try
    {
        bs.LinkNavigator.Navigate(new Uri("/Pages/AddGame.xaml", UriKind.Relative), this);
    }
    catch (Exception error)
    {
        ModernDialog.ShowMessage(error.Message, FirstFloor.ModernUI.Resources.NavigationFailed, MessageBoxButton.OK);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Lukas. You saved my life. And how can I activate the link as well, which is mui:Link.

Comment: Sorry, but I don't know what do you mean: "..how can I activate link.."

Comment: I am using Modern UI as i mentioned in my Question. and Modern UI uses link for navigation. So i am asking about those links. like below
        <mui:LinkGroup DisplayName="Tool to add or update games" >
            <mui:LinkGroup.Links>
                <mui:Link DisplayName="Home" Source="Pages/Home.xaml" />
                <mui:Link DisplayName="Add Game" Source="Pages/AddGame.xaml" />
                <mui:Link DisplayName="Update Game" />
                <mui:Link DisplayName="Automation Files" />
            </mui:LinkGroup.Links>
       </mui:LinkGroup>
</mui:ModernWindow.MenuLinkGroups>

Answer (score 0):

Interestingly, in my environment, the following code works:

```
if (App.HasDashboardRole)
            {
                App.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke(new Action(() =>
                {
                    var bs = new BBCodeBlock();
                    bs.LinkNavigator.Navigate(new Uri("/Pages/Dashboard.xaml", UriKind.Relative), this);
                }));
            }
            else if (App.HasBarcodeBuilderRole)
            {
                App.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke(new Action(() =>
                {
                    var bs = new BBCodeBlock();
                    bs.LinkNavigator.Navigate(new Uri("/Pages/BarcodeBuilderPage.xaml", UriKind.Relative), this);
                }));
            }
```

When this code does not:

```
App.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke(new Action(() =>
                {
                    var bs = new BBCodeBlock();
                    if (App.HasDashboardRole)
                        bs.LinkNavigator.Navigate(new Uri("/Pages/Dashboard.xaml", UriKind.Relative), this);
                    else if (App.HasBarcodeBuilderRole)
                        bs.LinkNavigator.Navigate(new Uri("/Pages/BarcodeBuilderPage.xaml", UriKind.Relative), this);
                }));
```